# Hire a scooter near San Javier Airport, Spain?

Tags: airports, spain, scooters

I'm going on a trip to Spain. We would like to hire two scooters (50cc) for +-10 days. We arrive in the San Javier airport in Murcia. What would be the nearest (or a few nearest) to rent those?

I've searched all over the web but can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

The only motorbike/scooter place I found was these guys

http://motoalcazares.blogspot.com.es

They have an office in Lo Pagan. Which is sort of close to the airport

You can also see some bike hire options here if you want to get your pedal on

http://costacalida.angloinfo.com/af/548/costa-calida-bike-hire-scooter-and-cycle-rental.html